# Turning on auto-expunge emails in Dekko?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email, delete

When I delete an email, it is apparently marked as deleted but not fully removed (expunged/or moved to trash). It stays crossed over in the INBOX folder. I read around (https://bugs.launchpad.net/dekko/+bug/1415132) that there is some auto-expurge option but cannot find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-expunge feature was disabled in accounts settings a while back, but will be re-enabled in a coming update. For the time being you will need to expunge manually from the contextual actions of the mailbox in question. You will see an "Expunge mailbox" option.